# Bresenham line drawing fails for a particular co-ordinate?

Tags: c++, graphics, line

The code works fine first call of `positionGenerator(1046,1623,750,1290);` but runs into an infinite loop in the second call `positionGenerator(1046,1623,375,810);` .

```
  #include<iostream>
  #include<string>
  #include<cmath>
  using namespace std;



void positionGenerator(int xa,int ya, int xb,int yb)
{
int dx=0,dy=0,x_inc=0,y_inc=0,m=0,p=0,i=0;
dx=xb-xa;
dy=yb-ya;
m=dy/dx;
x_inc=dx>0?2:-2;
y_inc=dy>0?2:-2;
cout<<"x_incr"<<x_inc<<"y_incr"<<y_inc<<endl;
cout<<"dx"<<dx<<"dy"<<dy<<endl;
dx=abs(dx);
dy=abs(dy);
cout<<"dx"<<dx<<"dy"<<dy<<endl;
p=(2*dy)-(dx);
for(i=1;((xa!=xb) && (ya!=yb));i++)
{
    if(p>0)
    {
        xa=xa+x_inc;
        ya=ya+y_inc;
        p=p+(2*dy)-(2*dx);
    }
    else
    {
        if(m<1)
        {
            xa=xa+x_inc;
            p=p+(2*dy);
        }
        else
        {
            ya=ya+y_inc;
            p=p-(2*dx);
        }

    }

cout<<"x"<<xa<<"y"<<ya<<endl;

  }
 }

int main()
{
     //first_call
     positionGenerator(1046,1623,750,1290);

    //second_call
     positionGenerator(1046,1623,375,810);
     return 0;
}
```

I believe the algorithm works for both positive and negative slope .

Comment: Since you increase/decrease with `2` every loop, think about what happens if `xa` is even while `xb` is uneven (and the same for `ya`/`yb`)?

Answer (score 1):

You should count the number of pixels along the axis with the longest line projection instead of relying on `(xa!=xb) && (ya!=yb)`. And then there may be some other bugs to fix.

Answer (score 1):

You have problem in condition `((xa!=xb) && (ya!=yb))`

Increment value is equal 2 for both x and y.
Therefore you should have at least one value from (xb-xa) and (yb-ya) will be even.
However you have two odd differences for the second call.

Answer (score 0):

Your current loop termination condition will never be true when the distances |xa-xb| and |ya-yb| are both odd.

You need to find a better termination condition.